# IObservable<T> in .NET Framework 4.0 Beta2

Tags: .net-4.0, namespaces, system.reactive

`IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>` interfaces are placed directly in the `System` namespace in .NET Framework 4.0 Beta2. Why not in `System.Collections.Generic`, like `IEnumerable<T>`?

p.s. Reactive Framework preview from Silverlight Toolkit contains `IObserver<T>` in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that new IObservable/IObserver interfaces describe is an abstraction much higher than just collections which can be seen as a special case of computations (that's why lists in Haskell are monads). So it's obvious that such generalization is placed to System namespace.

Take a look at [this brilliant cast](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Expert-to-Expert-Brian-Beckman-and-Erik-Meijer-Inside-the-NET-Reactive-Framework-Rx/) from Erik Meijer where he describes the ideas behind the interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

[IObservable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362412(SQL.105).aspx) is an interface that identifies a class that implements the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern. Its not related to Collections. Its more related to providing an alternative to Events.

Comment: IObservable<T> is a dualism for IEnumerable<T>, it's not only related to events, collections may be observable too :) It's just push-based IEnumerable<T> at first look. ReactiveFramework in the Silverlight Toolkit contains IObservable<T> and IObserver<T> interfaces at System.Collections.Generic namespace as I expect, but not in .NET 4.0

Comment: You're not making any sense, ControlFlow.  Of course collections may be observable.  But the fact that a collection may be observable doesn't mean that anything observable is a collection.  There are plenty of generic interfaces and types in the CLI that aren't in System.Collections.Generic.

Comment: @ControlFlow: IObservable<T>/IObserver<T> have nothing to do with collections specifically. Sure, a collection could be observable, but so can non-collections. Observation is a lower-level thing than collections, intended to support the **observer** pattern in a more decoupled, less language-specific way (i.e. alternative to C# events). It is most definitely *not* a dualism for IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: @ControlFlow: The System.Collections.Generic namespace is for *System* defined *Collections* that are *Generic*.  IObservable is system-defined, and it is generic, but it isn't a collection; An instance of a class implementing IObservable is a single thing, not a group of things.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question I stumbled upon, I just wanted to back @ControlFlow's assessment of the 'dualism' between IObservable and IEnumerable as a 'Pushed based' vs 'Pull based' collection with a link to Erik Meijer's 'Rx in 15 Minutes', where he can be quoted as saying exactly that. http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Charles/Erik-Meijer-Rx-in-15-Minutes/

Consequently, this pushed-based collection can fundamentally shift the basic paradigm of 'a mundane series of called events' into an asynchronous, selectable, query-able, passable and subscribe-able first-class collection of declarative actionable.  Something that does that belongs in the core BCL namespace or perhaps deserves it's own, but is too far beyond Yet-Another-Collection to share its namespace.  Mind you, that's just my opinion.